# Each model Ember not listing the models in template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, jsbin

I am using Ember.RSVP.hash to create different models in the same route, i successfully create  the model records in the store, i can see the data in the console.
[image]

The problem is that i can only list one the two models in my template. ( repos name but not the commit message ).

Here the code

Route

```
    var gitrepositoriesPromise = function() {
        return Ember.$.ajax(reposUrl, {
          success: function(repos) {
            return repos.map(function(repo) {
                return store.createRecord('repo', {
                    name: repo.name,
                    description: repo.description
                });
            });
          },
          error: function(reason) {
             reject(reason);
          }});

    };

    var gitactivitiesPromise = function() {
        return Ember.$.ajax(eventsAct, {
            success: function(events) {
                return events.filter(function(event) {
                    return event.type == 'PushEvent';
                }).forEach(function(item){
                    return item.payload.commits.map(function(commit){
                        return store.createRecord('commit', {
                            message: commit.message,
                        });
                    });
                });
            },  
            error: function(reason) {
             reject(reason);
        }});             
    };      



    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
        commits: gitactivitiesPromise(),
        repos: gitrepositoriesPromise()
    });
```

Template

```
   <ul>
    {{#each model.repos}}        
      <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
   </ul>
   <ul>
    {{#each model.commits}}  
       <li>{{message}}</li>
    {{/each}}
   </ul>
```

So the problem must be here in

```
{{#each model.commits}}  
   <li>{{message}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

What am i doing wrong? [here the jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kuqejahele/edit?html,js,output) reproducing the issue.

Comment: I am not sure where the problem is but I have realized that in the `jsbin` there are 30 dots for the commits and your model only have 26 records (as it is shown in Ember inspector). Maybe `Ember.RSVP.hash` is not working as expected. Could it be a bug related to the version of `Ember` that you are using?

Comment: I have tried to return only the commits without `RSVP` and it does the same, so the problem is in your function `gitactivitiesPromise`.

Comment: well since i can see the model data ( console image in attached ) i think that gitactivitiesPromise is not the problem

Comment: Your records are correctly created but what you are returning is the whole list of events, so no, it is not correct. Use the `{{log}}` helper with the commits and see it by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so problem was in your `gitactivitesPromise` function. I've modified your approach to use `Ember.RSVP.hash`:

```
var gitactivitiesPromise = function() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) {
    Ember.$.ajax(eventsAct, {
      success: function(events) {
        var result = [];
        events.filter(function(event) {
          return event.type == 'PushEvent';
        }).forEach(function(item){
          item.payload.commits.map(function(commit){
            result.push(store.createRecord('commit', {
              message: commit.message,
            }));
          });
        });
        resolve(result);
      },  
      error: function(reason) {
        reject(reason);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

This lets you to access `message` this way in template:

```
Commits:
<ul>
  {{#each model.commits}}
    <li>{{this.message}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

[Working demo.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zevalapeme/2/edit?html,js,output)